# Remote Desktop change position of desktop icons

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, desktop

Sometimes i have to connect with remote desktop to remote workstations with the user's login.

What happens sometimes is after closing the remote session and the user opens the local session all desktop icons are re-arranged and mis-placed. So the user has to place the icons where there are before. Very annoying.

Is there a way to avoid this ? Thank you.

**Update**

That is a really Windows enigma, annoying all Windows user's (even when you change screen resolution on local) and no solution. Remote Desktop should (with option) advise you are connecting to a remote system with higher resolution.

Thanks for your tips, i will go with [that](http://www.webtlk.com/2008/08/08/restore-the-position-of-desktop-icons-after-changing-screen-resolution/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have equal desktop resolution in local and remote sessions? No? That's the reason!

Google for e.g. "desktop items position saving" and select most suitable for you from tons of possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

[**Save And Restore Desktop Icon Positions**](http://www.optimizingpc.com/install/desktopandscreen.html) with [**IconRestorer**](http://fsl.sytes.net/iconrestorer.html).

> With IconRestorer you can backup the icon locations and, when needed, restore them easily to the location at the time of the backup.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to save your connections settings to an Rdp file than edit the file and adjust the *desktopwidth* and *desktopheight* properties to match the remote screen resolution.

This has been discussed [here](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-networking-sharing/184433-desktop-icons-scambled-using-remote-desktop.html). Hope this helps.